# Android sqlite UPDATE not works properly

Tags: android, sqlite

I referred the following pages but still my problem is not solved,

[Android sqlite update table always return 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051097/android-sqlite-update-table-always-return-0)  , [SQLite in Android How to update a specific row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798473/sqlite-in-android-how-to-update-a-specific-row)  , [Android SQLite update row not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818426/android-sqlite-update-row-not-working) , [Update Function in android SQLite is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119589/update-function-in-android-sqlite-is-not-working) and [SQLiteDatabase update not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532859/sqlitedatabase-update-not-working)

I have a sqlite database as QUESTIONS(ID,QUES,ANS),ID is the primary key. When i try to update a value using following code no change happens in the database.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = null;
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("QUES","New title");
values.put("ANS","Answer" );
long k= db.update("QUESTIONS",values,"ID=2",null);
Log.d("Success",""+k);
```

The value of k is 1, And there is no change in database. I also tried with

```
long k= db.update("QUESTIONS",values,null,null);
```

But no use .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first line sets `db` to be null.

You have no database configured for the `UPDATE` command to work on.

Comment: maybe you have configured a database in the code for that. The reason the above code doesn't work is given in my answer. It is impossible to update a database if the database reference is null.

Comment: i tried but it show message you can accept in 4 minutes

Comment: the mistake i did is i copied the insertion code from another class and attached to the new class but missed the   code   db = openOrCreateDatabase("datas", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```